# Выдает ошибку при цифре 01

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch, promise

Подскажите пожалуйста такая проблема, необходимо сделать список регионов с кодами автономеров, то есть регион:код региона. Это все необходимо обернуть в формат json. При написании региона 01, 02 и по 09 включительно выдается ошибка. Пишет, что необходимо использовать точку. Но как там использовать точку если это цифра региона, на скрине видно.
Благодарю за помощь.

[image: На скрине видно, что цифра 01 подчеркнута как ошибка]

Comment: 01 в данном случае это не число, а строка. Обернитье 01 в кавычки, вот так `'01'`. И код лучше выкладывать текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: А остальные числа без ковычек, которые например 33,29 и т.д.

Comment: @russianBoy код региона это не число, а строка. Так что всё в кАвычках.

Comment: Смысл и целевое использование такого JSON-а это конечно отдельный вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not consider numbers with leading zeros to be valid
JSON не рассматривает числа с ведущим нулем как валидные

Comment: И как быть тогда?

Comment: @russianBoy это означает что он не поддерживает литералы, на самом деле проблем нет, просто используйте строки вместо чисел.

Comment: @ΝNL993, собственно использование чисел тоже не проблема, лидирующие нули в принципе не нужны, только для вывода.

Comment: @Grundy На самом деле да, можно обойдись и числами, а если нужно будет всё-таки нули добавить, тогда число в строку и используем метод `padStart`.